# Разрезать NSString на составляющие

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Подскажите, как вырезать из строки определённый текст? Например:
 NSString * String1 = @"12345result=678910"; ,
 вот мне нужно в
 NSString *String2 = @"678910";

размер после result= - динамический - может достигать от 1-го до 40-ка символов.

Answer (score 1):

Популярный вопрос. Я тоже влезу

```
NSString *res = @"122345result=678910";
NSRange position = [res rangeOfString:@"result="];
if(position.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *newString = [res substringFromIndex:position.location+position.length];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

использовал такую конструкцию:

```
NSArray  *data = [@"abc xyz http://www.abc.com aaa bbb ccc" componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for(NSString* str in data)
{
    if([NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]]])
        NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc ] initWithFormat:@"Found a URL: %@",str]);
}
```

Comment: что то ответ не подходит к вопросу

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае самое простое:

```
NSString *String1 = @"12345result=678910";
NSString *String2 = [String1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"12345result=" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Так будет немного универсальней:

```
NSString *string1 = @"12345result=678910";
NSArray *components = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString: @"="];
NSString *result = nil;
if( components.count == 2 )
        result = components[1];
```